# How to open other form and close current form using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms (Form1 & Form2). In Form1 have button click. When we click I want to open Form2 and close Form1 completely.
I have try to use:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();

frm.Show();

this.Close();
```

but it will close all form. so i try to use:

```
this.Hide();
```

but Form1 still have processing.
so does anyone know solution?

Comment: Well, most probably `this` in your example is the application main form, that's why closing it will exit the application.

Comment: Use `this.Dispose()`

Comment: @JaydipJ: `this.Close();` will call `this.Dispose();`

Comment: look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974599/c-sharp-opening-a-new-form-and-closing-the-other-one?rq=1